# Multiple from addresses from one account

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I want to add multiple from addresses to choose from with only one account in outlook.

For example;
I've one account a@example.com but want to be able to send mail as a@example.com and b@exam.com.

The usecase for this is that the email address b@exam.com is forwarded to a@example.com so from outlooks perspective there's only one account.

I've seen plenty of examples of how to do this with an outlook server and/or multiple outlook accounts. That's not the case here. It's POP3 and one account in this case.

Versionen är Microsoft Office Outlook 2007 SP3 MSO.

Answer (score 1):

Compose a new email, then go to Options and enable `From:`

A new `From:` button will appear in the compose window above `To...`

Click that, and select `Other email address...` and enter the email address you wish to send from.

This will remain as an option for future emails.

Comment: The problem is that I don't have the "Other email address..." option.

Comment: Can you add your outlook version to the question

Comment: I've added the version information you requested.